# Delete or straighten one of two anchor point handles in sketch 3

Tags: sketch-app

How would you go about deleting or straightening one anchor point handle, while keeping the opposite handle intact?

[image: sketch screen shot]

Comment: do you mean the anchor handle?

Answer (score 1):

I believe I know what you mean.

---

While drawing the vector path, you can force the "closest" handle to be retracted, if you press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> while you are about to create the next anchor point.

This is the only method I know of. I don't know if you can make this edit later, but I don't think you can.

[image]

---

Another method that comes to mind is to rely on the anchor points between straight anchor points to produce the curved line.

[image]

In this picture, the "straight" point basically means that I just clicked an anchor point there.

Answer (score 1):

I missed a function sorry guys. Under the Pencil tool there is a Disconnected function, if you tap that you will be able to manipulate the anchor handels separately

[image: pencil disconnected function]

Comment: You can disconnect the handles by pressing cmd while dragging or when you start to drag the handle. –– However, I would not recommend using this method. You can super easily generate bad corners this way. [Here's an example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d4mr4ddy2dqdmbo/vector-tool-example.png?raw=1). ––– If you really wanna do it this way, I would recommend dragging the handle towards the next anchor point, instead of it's own anchor point. Although that's not always ideal

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't have a fancy animation, but for others landing here, you can actually delete the 'inside handles' of any two points in a *closed* path:

1. Select the scissors tool and delete the line between two anchors
2. Press [esc] on the keyboard to exit the scissors tool
3. Double-clicking the shape to select it
4. Click the "Close Path" button in the top of the inspector window. This will 're-draw' the path segment you just deleted, except it will be perfectly straight (no handles). The handles on the other sides of the anchors will remain intact.

Note: If your path isn't closed to begin with, you can close it temporarily before you start so that the "Close Path" command works later (if you don't, you'll end up with two separate paths which can't be 'closed').

Cheers! Hope this helps someone :-)

[I'm using Sketch ver 46.1]